# Вывод даты из mysql на русском

Tags: php, mysql

На просторах интернета есть функция:

```
<?php
function gws_daterus($date) {
  // -- определяем массив для месяцев --
$mounth = array(
"01" => "января", 
"02" => "февраля", 
"03" => "марта", 
"04" => "апреля", 
"05" => "мая", 
"06" => "июня", 
"07" => "июля", 
"08" => "августа", 
"09" => "сентября", 
"10" => "октября", 
"11" => "ноября", 
"12" => "декабря");

// -- определяем массив для дней недели --
$week = array(
'воскресенье', 
'понедельник', 
'вторник', 
'среда', 
'четверг', 
'пятница', 
'суббота');

$date_m = strtr(date('m', $date), $mounth);
$date_w = $week [date('w', $date)];
$date_d = date('d', $date);
$date_y = date('Y', $date);

   return $date_d . " " . $date_m . " " . $date_y;
}
```

В таблице MySQL есть поле типа Date. При попытке вывести отформатированную дату при помощи функции gws_daterus() выводится "01 января 1970". Почему?

```
echo gws_daterus('2019-02-02');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не забываем преобразовывать нашу строку `$date` в метку времени unix, используя `strtotime()`

```
function gws_daterus($date) {
    // -- определяем массив для месяцев --
    $mounth = array("01" => "января", "02" => "февраля", "03" => "марта", 
                    "04" => "апреля", "05" => "мая", "06" => "июня", 
                    "07" => "июля", "08" => "августа", "09" => "сентября", 
                    "10" => "октября", "11" => "ноября", "12" => "декабря");
    // -- определяем массив для дней недели --
    $week = array('воскресенье', 'понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 
                    'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота');

    $date_m = strtr(date('m', strtotime($date)), $mounth);
    $date_w = $week [date('w', strtotime($date))];
    $date_d = date('d', strtotime($date));
    $date_y = date('Y', strtotime($date));

    return $date_d . " " . $date_m . " " . $date_y;
}

echo gws_daterus('2019-02-02');
```

Comment: жесть... Лучше делать через локаль и `date_parse_from_format`.